# QuickTime plugin not available for Firefox 9 on OS X?

Tags: macos, firefox, quicktime

I'm trying to watch an embedded video in QuickTime format, but there is no QuickTime plugin in Firefox 9.01 on Mac OS X Lion v10.7.2. It says:

> Additional plugins are required to display all media on this page. Install missing plugin?

I choose *Install Missing Plugin* and it says:

> No Suitable Plugins were found: Unknown plugin (video/quicktime).

Checking Software Update says everything is up to date on my computer, and QuickTime Player.app is installed in the applications directory. In Library/Internet Plugins there is a file called `QuickTime Plugin.plugin`.

In Firefox Add-Ons, under Plugins, there is no QuickTime plugin at all.

Comment: [Here's a site](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/object-video.html) that embeds a `video/quicktime` MIME type, if someone wants to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickTime should already come with your system. There's no separate plugin to install.

If you type `about:plugins` into the Firefox address  bar, you should see that the QuickTime 7.6.6 plugin offers support for the `video/quicktime` MIME type.

[image]

If you don't have this, then something is probably broken with your QuickTime installation.

---

[A solution](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11603475#11603475) I found was the following:

- Quit Firefox
- Move the `QuickTime Plugin.plugin` file from `Library/Internet Plugins` away (e.g. to the Desktop)
- Open Firefox again, go to *Tools » Add-ons » Plugins* to check that it's not recognized anymore
- Quit Firefox
- Move the `QuickTime Plugin.plugin` file back to where it was
- Open Firefox again

Comment: The solution of moving the quicktime plugin file worked, but only after I restarted my computer.